# Prove that the set of points in $\mathbb A^2 (\mathbb R)$ satisfying $r=\sin \theta$ is algebraic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was thinking about the following problem:

> Show that the set of points $\mathbb A^2 (\mathbb R)$, which in polar coordinates satisfy the equation: $r=\sin\theta$ is an algebraic set.

Now I need to find some polynomial in $\mathbb R[X,Y]$, or some set of polynomials that precisely have these points as common roots. We see that:

$$x=r \cos\theta $$
$$y=r \sin \theta=r^2=x^2+y^2$$

So the final equation tells me that my polynomial should be  $X^2+Y^2-Y$. However, I have not yet used the first equation and am not sure how. I was thinking of differentiating, but that got me nowhere. Any pointers?

Comment: Draw the picture. You're already done.

Comment: it's a circle.... lol you can just complete the square. Thanks. Completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a circle. To see this, complete the square in the equation
$$ x^2+y^2-y=0 $$
and then $V(X^2+Y^2-Y)$ is the set described in the problem.